# Write the output of os.walk into *.txt file

Tags: python-3.x, os.walk

I'm an absolute beginner with python. I want to write every file in a folder (the folder where the pythonscript is) in the files.txt file. When I run the script only with the for loop everthing works and I see every file of the folder. When I insert the file() function to write it to a file I only get the last folder in my textfile. Where is mz problem?

```
def dir_list():
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        print(name)
dir_list()
```

works fine and print the files.

Now with the file():

```
def dir_list():
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        file = open("files.txt", "w")
        file.write(name + "\n")
        file.close()

dirlist()
```

I hope you can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: You are opening the file for writing and thus truncating it each time. You need to open it once, with a `with` statement, before the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you are reopening the file every time you go through the loop, and since you're opening it in write mode (by passing "w" as a parameter of the open function) the previous content of the file gets overwritten and in the end only the content written in the last iteration is saved.

To solve this you should open the file only once before entering the loop:

```
def dir_list():
   with open("files.txt", "a") as fp:
      for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
         for name in dirs:
           fp.write(name + "\n")

dirlist()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, you're overwriting the file for every entry.  Try
the following:

```
def dir_list():
    with open("files.txt", "a") as fp:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
            for name in dirs:
                fp.write(name + "\n")

dirlist()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dir_list():
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        file = open("files.txt", "a+")
        print(name + "\n",file=file)
        file.close()

dirlist()
```

Hope this will work and this is a very simple way to printing all output of a for loop.
And here the "a+" means that you are appending the output
Know me is it works or not in your python environment